# Implementing Logistic Regression: weights matrix becoming singular

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, classification, least-squares

I am implementing Logistic Regression via Iteratively Re-weighted Least Squares (in Rust for what its worth). The iterative procedure is:

$$
\mathbf{w}_{k+1}
= (\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{S}_k \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^T (\mathbf{S}_k \mathbf{X} \mathbf{w}_k + \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{\mu}_k)
$$

I am running into the problem of the diagonal weights matrix ($\mathbf{S}_k$) becoming singular (the diagonal entries are converging to zero).

Are there any references that specifically discuss how to deal with this issue ?

The only solution I found was to add a slight adjustment to the diagonal entries, so something like:

$$
\mathbf{S}_k + \epsilon \mathbf{I}
$$

However, many choices of $\epsilon$ that I have tried cause it to either diverge (overshoot the solution; start way off) or take a very long time to converge. This "solution" seems hacky to say the least.